# jQuery Ajax calls causing the .htaccess protection session to be reset

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, .htaccess

I've protected a domain with .htaccess password protection.

In the website (PHP website) under this domain I have code that is sending ajax requests by jQuery to web services in the same website (same origin).

Previously the ajax calls were working perfectly, but after I added the .htaccess protection, the calls are giving 404, and every time a call is sent, the ".htaccess session" is somehow wiped because when I do refresh I get the same .htaccess login message again.

From my understanding this should not happen because both the page that is calling the webservice, and the webservice itself are in the same origin so no CORS issue here.

I tried to add basic authorization to the ajax requests, I can see the Authorization part is being sent correctly with the request, but the behavior is still the same.

.htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

jQuery:

```
handleAJAXCall: function (actionUrl, method, dataValues, doneFunction, failFunction) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: actionUrl,
            data: dataValues,
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            doneFunction(response);

        }).fail(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            failFunction(response);
        });
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Any chance its bouncing around between http and https? Maybe not, but I thought I'd ask. Also, do you have a snip example from the htaccess on how you set it up?

Comment: ...and the Ajax request that includes the Basic Auth.

Comment: @Randall I thought first about http/https case, but no it's not.

Comment: Well I got nothing ;) I use this exact kind of setup on a test server, and its riddled with ajax with jquery (all kinds too!). It all works, never ran into this issue, so I'm both baffled, and a bit spooked why its not working for you.